# start all servlets at application launch

Tags: java, initialization, servlets

I have a web application which has two servlets that exchange information through context attributes.

Each servlet depends on the information that the other servlet sets in the context attributes. For example if I first access servlet S1, I need to access information that is provided by servlet S2, through context attributes, I make a request (through `URLConnection`) to S2.

I  need servlets S1 and S2 to start (be initialized) at application launch, not when a request is made to them.

Is there any configuration I can make, so that all servlets in my application are initialized at launch time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `web.xml` (the deployment descriptor):

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SomeServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.SomeServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> <!-- this is the element -->
</servlet>
```

Explanations:

- [What does the servlet <load-on-startup> value signify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809775/what-does-the-servlet-load-on-startup-value-of-0-zero-signify)
- http://geekexplains.blogspot.com/2008/06/what-does-load-on-startup-element-mean.html
- http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/Web.xml.LoadOnStartup

Comment: Explanations here : http://geekexplains.blogspot.com/2008/06/what-does-load-on-startup-element-mean.html