# Where should I place clean up code inside a web application?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, servlets

I have the following problem:
I need to run some clean up code from various of classes loaded as part of a web application in Tomcat.
Cleanup code ranges from shutting down `executors` to database clean-up code.
I tried and found out (and learned afterwards that this is documented as such) that:

> All servlets and filters will have been destroyed **before** any
>   ServletContextListeners are notified of context destruction.

So this rules out running the clean up code in any `ServletContextListeners`.
I put the clean up code in the `destroy` method of a `Servlet`, but realized that if the client does not require its use it will *never* be loaded and as a result the clean up code in the `destroy` method will never run.
So now I am stuck.
Where is the best place to put clean up code in a web application since e.g. if I put it in a `servlet` I can not ensure that the client will use that and if I put it in a `listener` it is too late?

Comment: I don't get why you're not happy with registering a ServletContextListener in your webapp. What's the problem with servlets and filters being destroyed first ? You don't want your cleaning to occur when some servlets are still working.

Comment: What exactly do you need to do in your "clean-up" code?

Comment: @dystroy:Because my classes have already been unloaded on shutdown before getting a chance to run the clean up code in the `ServletContextListener`.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen:From shutdown `executors` to closing a database

Comment: You have the option to implement `DisposableBean` or configure with `destroy-method`. See [here](http://www.javabeat.net/2007/10/life-cycle-management-of-a-spring-bean/).

Comment: The classes needed by your ServletContextListener are still there. I use this perfectly standard solution to clean up my webapps.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik:Right now, unfortunatelly, I have not used Spring in my web app.Is it possible to do this without introducing Spring?

Comment: In that case I haven't got the first idea on your app's homebrewn architecture.

Comment: @dystroy:But they are not.I get exception and errors like: `Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik:It is an "old-fashioned" servlet application with a database back-end.Not sure what other info you would find useful

Comment: Why do you not let the container manage threads and database connection pool?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen:I need to run an executor in some case for some long running tasks.Also the connection pool is handled by the container but for this specific database (H2) I need to explicitely shut it down

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option to configure your servlet to load on startup, that would get around the problem as stated.

See [What does the servlet <load-on-startup> value signify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809775/what-does-the-servlet-load-on-startup-value-of-0-zero-signify) for an example and some discussion.