# How to run a program automatically when just glassfish server is started?

Tags: java, glassfish-3

I want my java web application run a program automatically when i start or deploy the program  in glassfish server. My web application need to run a mail program inside glassfish when just deployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up a servlet to run on application startup, or possibly use the @Singleton annotation, depending on whether you want EJB involved.  Or if you're using Spring, there are more ways.  You could give some more background for better answers.

[What does the servlet <load-on-startup> value signify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809775/what-does-the-servlet-load-on-startup-value-of-0-zero-signify)

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/JavaEE/JavaEE6Overview_Part3.html#singles

Comment: I am using JSF. How can i do that by JSF. i just need to run a single java program automatically when web application run.

Comment: Sorry I don't know JSF, but I imagine it starts with some kind of servlet.  But if I google "jsf startup bean" I find things like: http://jfindings.blogspot.com/2009/04/creating-startup-listener-in-jsf.html  where you can do things with ContextLoaderListener, ServletContextListener, web.xml, `@Component`, and `@Scope` to get the behavior I'm guessing you're looking for.  Sounds complicated.

Comment: Thanks Jim. I just want that when i start my web application it will send email automatically  at specified time from database. i wrote the mail class but i need to run the mail class internally as i run the web application.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set some flag type attribute in your database and change the value after run the program.