# An approach for loading large resources on Java application start up

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a Java application hosted in a Tomcat servlet container which queries a database and creates an in-memory model (very big) with the results. The code to create the in-memory graph takes around 3 minutes to run so I'm keen to be able to do this as the application is started and before the users can access the application.

Is there a typical patterned approach for doing this?

Comment: Why is this model in memory at all?

Comment: Also, have you considered using some caching solution, like for instance, ehcache? Or, more simple, Guava's LoadingCache?

Answer (score 4):

A recommended way to do that is to implement a `javax.servlet.ServletContextListener` and to run your code inside `contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent)`.

Then add this to your web.xml

```
<listener>
 <listener-class>com.company.LoadEverythingINeedListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

This will ensure that your users won't access your application before you're ready.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a `<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>` parameter from a servlet, or maybe a context listener to do it.

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809775/what-does-the-servlet-load-on-startup-value-of-0-zero-signify and http://www.devmanuals.com/tutorials/java/servlet/ContextListenerExample.html