# Why does Spring-MVC set LoadOnStartup to 1?

Tags: spring-mvc

I want to know why set this value to 1.I read the api,it means Sets the loadOnStartup priority on the Servlet represented by this dynamic ServletRegistration.Why is 1?

I read a piece of code :

```
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
            throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(WebAppConfig.class);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));

        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);
        Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm adding to this answer in case anyone else happens upon this post.  Based on the documentation this is more complicated than 1 = true and 0 = false.  The value is a priority defining the ORDER in which applications that do initialize on startup will be invoked.

[ServletRegistration.Dynamic.setLoadOnStartup](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRegistration.Dynamic.html#setLoadOnStartup%28int%29)

This was covered in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809775/what-does-the-servlet-load-on-startup-value-signify).

Answer (score 2):

Ahh 1 is the convention for true. 0 is convention for false. You set load on startup for the dispatcher servlet so the spring container will be initialized on app server (tomcat etc) startup.

Answer (score 1):

setLoadOnStartup:

```
void setLoadOnStartup(int loadOnStartup)
```

Sets the `loadOnStartup` priority on the Servlet represented by this dynamic ServletRegistration.

A `loadOnStartup` value of greater than or equal to zero indicates to the container the initialization priority of the `Servlet`. In this case, the container must instantiate and initialize the `Servlet` during the initialization phase of the `ServletContext`, that is, after it has invoked all of the `ServletContextListener` objects configured for the `ServletContext` at their `ServletContextListener#contextInitialized` method.

If `loadOnStartup` is a negative integer, the container is free to instantiate and initialize the `Servlet` lazily.

The default value for `loadOnStartup` is -1.

A call to this method overrides any previous setting.

```
 Parameters:
        loadOnStartup - the initialization priority of the Servlet 
    Throws:
        IllegalStateException - if the ServletContext from which this ServletRegistration was obtained has already been initialized
```