# load on startup value example code in xml

Tags: java, servlets

**load-on-startup can specify an (optional) integer value. If the value is 0 or greater, it indicates an order for servlets to be loaded, servlets with higher numbers get loaded after servlets with lower numbers.**

I found this statement when I searched about load on startup. I can not clear how it works. Please show me an example for servlets with *different load on startup number order*.

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809775/what-does-the-servlet-load-on-startup-value-signify

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the servlet <load-on-startup> value signify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809775/what-does-the-servlet-load-on-startup-value-signify)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well if you had four servlets

```
servlet1 with value 1 would start first
servlet2 with value 2 would start next
servlet3 with value 3 would start next
servlet4 with value 0 would start manually
```

Comment: Like this? 
<servlet>
<servlet-name>servlet1</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>myClass1</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup></servlet>
<servlet><servlet-name>servlet2</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>myClass2</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup></servlet>
<servlet><servlet-name>servlet3</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>myClass3</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

Comment: yep, `<load-on-startup>` is correct - see http://www.xyzws.com/servletfaq/what-is-%3Cloadonstartup%3E-in-webxml-file/24