# In Java, where do I find the class of execution at run time if no main class/method is used?

Tags: java, mainclass

I am trying to find where the entry point is of a large application, but I was told that it doesn't use a main class. I'm able to run and build the application, and I know that the classes and methods are executing when I make small changes.

However,  now I'm trying to embed a new class and I can't seem to find the entry point where these classes are called. Is there a way to find out where that is, so I can call this new class I created at run time? Thank you.

Comment: Please tell us more about this Java application.  Is it a web app, a console app, a Swing application, Android, something else?

Comment: Java application can't run without entry-point.  Is it a service(does java application use service wrapper service to run)?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It is an internal computer software application hosted on private cloud. I usually commit and push the changes, then run a build on Jenkins specifying the repository and it builds the war file and deploys to the cloud environment. I was advised to run it this way instead of locally since it's simpler, and I've had a look at the logs of the build but it doesn't show which class is called etc. Hope that helps? Thank you for getting back.

Comment: @WGSSAMINTHA Yes I know it has to run with an entry point, my question is _where_ can I find that. I'm not sure what you mean by a service wrapper? But it is a service indeed, our clients download the application with the URL.

Comment: `builds the war file` for anyone still reading.

Comment: In case of a web application that runs on some kind of web server, check your servlet configuration (web.xml). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809775/what-does-the-servlet-load-on-startup-value-signify for details on how to interpret the values there.

Comment: For more general information about servlet containers and how they work, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-sessions-shared-variables-and-multithreadi?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

its difficult to map this question because I do not know what you are building. But if its web application:

- Start looking at the entry Servlets and start seeing the classes that are being called that may have some service related to what you build.
- Also start looking at classes which has services it may be there, then again I'm not sure what you are building.

If its a client application FX,Swing and other you should look trough main and follow.

- public static void main(){// follow the flow}

Now if its very big I would recommend that you commit and push then if you are using eclipse do this.

Right click above the class -> **find references in project|workspace.**

This will find everywhere you your code is being called.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am using IntelliJ and I have right-clicked on the folder of all classes -> **Find in Path...**
I've searched for `public static void main` and nothing comes up.

Comment: Do not search for public static void main but search for the class that you made.

Answer (score 0):

In the IDE create debug mode using Edit configuration as Application and search for the main class where you will get displayed with files where the application starts