# Perform request to itself after the tomcat web server has launched

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, servlet-3.0

How to make call in server to the same server on startup using Spring (not spring boot)? Server - external Tomcat web server.

I have already tried to use `ContextRefreshedEvent` and `ServletContextListener` without success (always return 404).
Any ideas?

Comment: What do you need to achieve?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza
I need something like ```ApplicationReadyEvent``` in Spring Boot.

Comment: why not implement a servlet with a load-on-startup ? See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/809775/7748072)